# R programming: set output of for loop into a vector?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

For a data frame (x,y), I'm trying to find the possible combinations of all the slopes (i.e. `S[ij]=(y[j]-y[i])/(x[j]-x[i]) for i=!=j`).
I'm trying to find all the possible `x[j]-x[i]`, and `y[j]-y[i]` then dividing these two vectors. but the code does not work.

```
q=function(x){
for (i in 1:length(x)){
for (j in 1:length(x)){
g=x[j]-x[i]
print(as.vector(g))
}}}
```

I tried `print(g)` instead of `print(as.vector(g))` but it does not work. it gives me individual results when i used `print(g)`.

Anyway to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Can you provide sample data and output?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to run your function by defining a simple `x` vector and then after defining the function, calling it and passing it the `x` object. Does this work for you?

```
    x <- 1:3

    q <- function(x){
      for (i in 1:length(x)){
        for (j in 1:length(x)){
          g <- x[j]-x[i]
          print(g)
        }
      }
    }

    q(x)
```